# Java multiple GUI windows creation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have made a simple GUI using a `GridLayout(5,3)` , it is action performed and it implements action listener as well. The are some calculation and algorithms that working according to what inputs or buttons the user provides. Everything works just fine up to this point.

At some point in my code, the user gets a pop up massage that he is correctly logged in to the system using this common method `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(....)`  . All i want is, after he press the OK button, is to create an additional form that pop ups, and looks similar to the one above i made with `GridLayout(5,3)` so that my user can store additional info about him.

I really cant get it to work, and i have no idea how to start this.

Any ideas are very welcomed! Cheers and thanks in advance  :)

if add this:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container pane = getContentPane();
            GridLayout grid=new GridLayout(10,1);
            pane.setLayout(grid);
```

it only adds more lines to my gridlayout. And all above buttons and labels remains. How can i get rid of the previous labels and buttons?

Comment: What have you tried and how isn't it working? Putting all arguments about showing multiple windows aside, I'd gear my code towards creating a JPanel. Then I would put the main JPanel in a JFrame. I would then create a new main JPanel when desired and put it in a JDialog if I want a second window displayed with the same GUI.

Comment: 1+ on @RaptorDotCpp's comment, if only for the *et voilà*, but also for the good advice! Oops -- where'd it go?

Comment: hmm i cant see his comment :S

Comment: It was similar to mine. Well how about my suggestion?

Comment: well, ill try it and see how it goes.

Comment: i have update my question, if anyone cares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> if add this:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container pane = getContentPane();
GridLayout grid=new GridLayout(10,1);
pane.setLayout(grid);
```

> it only adds more lines to my gridlayout. And all above buttons and labels remains. How can i get rid of the previous labels and buttons?

You have at least three options if you want to swap "views" on the JFrame.

- If you want to use the same GUI with the same JTextComponents but have the components empty of text, then you'll need to go through your text components and call `setText("")` on all of them. If you want to keep the same JButtons and labels but change their text, then similarly you will need to go through all of them calling `setText("something else")`.
- If you want totally new components to replace the old ones, the most straight forward way I believe is to use a CardLayout to hold your JPanel that has all your components. When you want to swap the JPanel for another, make sure that the new JPanel has been added to the CardLayout-using JPanel and then call next() on the CardLayout object.
- Another way is to manually swap out JPanels held by the JFrame's contentPane by calling `removeAll()` on the contentPane, then `add(nextJPanel)` on it, then `revalidate()`, then `repaint()`.